# UIWebView, SearchBar, and TabBar not resizing correctly after the view is reloaded in landscape?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uisearchbar, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I have a tabbar application that shows a web browser in one tab. When you rotate the view everything works fine but when you switch to another tab and then go back to that tab in landscape, the view webview, searchbar, and toolbar go back to the portrait layout.This is the code I used but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#define isPortrait [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] ==     UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

if(isPortrait)
{
    browser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 68, 320, 408);
    addressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 23, 320, 44);
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 478, 320, 44);
}
else
{
    browser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 68, 320, 408);
    addressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 23, 320, 44);
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 478, 320, 44);
}
```

This is all in my viewdidload method.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
        browser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 68, 568, 160);
        addressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 23, 568, 44);
        toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 227, 568, 44);
    }
}
```